# Does !isNetworkError() guarantee that getResponse() will be non-null?

Tags: nullpointerexception, retrofit

I feel silly for such a simple yes or no answer but would rather not pepper my code with unnecessary null checks and I'm not confident I have looked through the source correctly.

```
RetrofitError error;
...
if (!error.isNetworkError()) 
    error.getResponse().getStatus();
```

Does the above code have a NPE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of an unexpected error in Retrofit `getResponse` would return null.  You take a look at the source [here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit/RestAdapter.java#L397).

In that specific case it wouldn't be a Network error and no `Response` would be available.